# Enviar correo que no sea gmail por php

Tags: php

he cargado a un servidor gratuito un programa donde al enviar información se envía un correo de aviso, pero solo se puede enviar a correo gmail y no a outlook, quisiera saber si es algo de la programación o es que solo se puede para gmail.

gracias

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $from = "no-reply@ejemplo.com";
        $to = "valen.h.m@outlook.com";
        $subject = "Solicitud Combustible";
        $message = "Se a realizado una solicitud de Combustible";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

?>

Comment: Las protecciones antispam SPF y DKIM son las que posiblemente no te permitan recibir el correo

Comment: Es mas allá de la programación, depende de la configuración del correo donde se ejecuta el php. Revisa si `error_get_last()` te devuelve algo.

Answer (score 0):

LA cabecera *FROM* debe ser de tu hosting. Por ejemplo, si usas digitalocean.com, debe ser algo como:

```
 $from = no-reply@digitalocean.com
```